# AWS Cognito integrating in flutter 3.0

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, authentication, exception, amazon-cognito

I use `amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2: ^3.5.0` to integrate AWS cognito in my app mobile.

To log in successfully, my users must enter their username and then answer a challenge that comes to their email and enter the 6 digits in my app.

for this, I am using:

```
await Auth.initiateAuth(authDetails);
```

This method returns an exception saying `CUSTOM_CHALLENGE` (which is valid and expected given my custom flow).

then with:

```
Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(verificationCode);
```

I send the 6 digits entered by the user, but this is where the problems begin, because according to `sendCustomChallengeAnswer` I am missing the session parameter, which in theory should be filled with the `initiateAuth` response, but this method does not respond to a session object, otherwise which response to a string of its exception called `CUSTOM_CHALLANGE`.

Any idea how I can solve this?

link package I'm using:  https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2

I need to know if it is a misinterpretation or a package error.

Comment: have you find a solution?